# How can I promisfy these functions?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using Node.js and the [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promises library.

This code works exactly the way I want:

```
/*
 * Try using Bluebird promisify():
 * - "Good" case: this works perfectly.  
 *   ... but it DOESN'T use "promisify()"; it creates a new promise for each function.
 * - SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *     callABC()...
 *     a():  [ 'a' ]
 *     b():  [ 'a', 'b' ]
 *     c():  [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
 *     Done: results: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] 
 */
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var a = function (results) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      results.push("a");
      console.log("a(): ", results);
      resolve(results);
    }, 15);
  });
}

var b = function (results) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      results.push("b");
      console.log("b(): ", results);
      resolve(results);
    }, 5);
  });
}

var c = function (results) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      results.push("c");
      console.log("c(): ", results);
      resolve(results);
    }, 10);
  });
}


var callABC = function (results) {
  console.log("callABC()...");
  a(results)
  .then(b)
  .then(c)
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log("Done: results:", results);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  });
}

callABC([]);
```

I understand that manually instantiating your own promises like this can be considered "bad":

- [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Q: How can I "promisify" the above snippet?

I've tried many things; none of them have worked. For example:

```
/*
 * Try using Bluebird promisify():
 * - Fails: never calls b() or c() 
 */
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var a = Promise.promisify(function (results) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    results.push("a");
    console.log("a(): ", results);
  }, 15);
});

var b = Promise.promisify(function (results) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    results.push("b");
    console.log("b(): ", results);
  }, 5);
});

var c = Promise.promisify(function (results) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    results.push("c");
    console.log("c(): ", results);
  }, 10);
});

var callABC = function (results) {
  console.log("callABC()...");
  a(results)
  .then(b)
  .then(c)
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log("Done: results:", results);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  });
}

callABC([]);
```

Q: What's the correct way to "promisify" the first example?

Q: In particular, how do I "resolve()" or "reject()" my callbacks if I substitute the automated `Promise.promisify()` or `Promise.promisifyAll()` for the manual `new Promise()`?  I imagine "throw" invokes `.catch()`, but is there another (better?) mechanism?

Q: Are there any restrictions?  For example, does the function need to have a callback parameter in order to be "promisified"?

Comment: `promisify` does not do magic. It only works for functions that take callbacks. See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for good use cases.

Comment: The correct way to solve this particular problem is to use `Promise.delay`, which is the promisified version of `setTimeout`. Try it.

Comment: @Bergi: 1) This is the answer I was looking for "promisify does not do magic. It only works for functions that take callbacks". 2) Thank you for the link. 3) "setTimeout()" was just for test purposes; it has nothing to do with the actual question.  4) If you'd like to put your comment in an "answer", I'd be happy to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: "not all JS functions can be promisified".  Specifically:

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

> Promise.promisify)... returns a function that will wrap the given
>   nodeFunction. Instead of taking a callback, the returned function will
>   return a promise whose fate is decided by the callback behavior of the
>   given node function. The node function should conform to node.js
>   convention of accepting a callback as last argument and calling that
>   callback with error as the first argument and success value on the
>   second argument.

So in the example above, "new Promise" is the correct approach: "Promise.promisify()" will not work.